# cant update data through array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am not able to update data through array in Codeigniter (PHP),

I want to update or set column `premium_id` and premium to 0 when column `premium_count` reduce to 0

Controller Function :-

```
$premium_count = !empty($logged_user[0]->premium_count) ? $logged_user[0]->premium_count : '0';

        if($premium_count == '0') {
            $data = array(
                'premium_count' => '0',
                'premium_id' => '0',
                'premium' => '0'
            );          
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'premium_count' => $premium_count-1
            );
        }
 $this->admin_model->updateData('users', $data, $this->session->userdata('userid'));
```

Model Function (sql Query) :-

```
public function updateData($table,$data,$id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update($table,$data);
}
```

It works when `premium_count` has value like 1,2,3.. but when it reduce to 0, It wont update or set above column to 0.

Comment: try by changing `$premium_count == '0'`  to `$premium_count == 0` or this `$premium_count === 0`

Comment: try to add "$this->db->last_query();" just after your update method and check what is the actual query executed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try and remove the quotes from 0s.
I mean change

```
    if($premium_count == '0') {
        $data = array(
            'premium_count' => '0',
            'premium_id' => '0',
            'premium' => '0'
        );
```

to

```
    if($premium_count == 0) {
        $data = array(
            'premium_count' => 0,
            'premium_id' => 0,
            'premium' => 0
        );
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

replace this part to place zero as integer instead of string

```
$premium_count = !empty($logged_user[0]->premium_count) ? $logged_user[0]->premium_count : 0;  // <- remove '' over zero
```

and check like this

```
    if($premium_count == 0) {   // <- remove '' over zero
       $data = array(
         'premium_count' => '0',
         'premium_id' => '0',
         'premium' => '0'
       );          
    } else {
        $data = array(
          'premium_count' => $premium_count-1
        );
    }
```